# Is it possible to assign different font sizes through CSS based on delimiters in the text?

Tags: html, css

We'd like to format the price on our magento website so it appears like Amazon.com without having to dig into the source code if it's possible.

[Amazon price display](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HiJF1.png)

We have a price format that would be RD$100.00 (first 3 characters always the same smaller, next numbers larger font up to the "." and then including and after that back to the smaller font)

Is this possible without adding further tags into the source code using REGEX?

Comment: No, this is not possible.  Styling can only be applied to elements (and pseudo-elements) in their entirety.

Comment: Without further tags the closest you can get is to look into Unicode subscripts and superscripts. For example a small dollar sign will be `&#xFE69;`.

Answer (score 1):

[image]

Hi Steve Pastor.

With just CSS it is not possible, to achieve the same result you need javascript

```html
<style>
    .price-container {
        font-family: Arial, sans-serif;
        font-size: 0;
    }

    .price-symbol {
        font-size: 18px;
        vertical-align: top;
        top: 7px;
            position: relative;
    }

    .current-price {
        font-size: 36px;
        font-weight: bold;
    }

    .current-price sup {
        font-size: 18px;
        font-weight: bold;
        position: relative;
        top: 1px;
    }

    .original-price {
        font-size: 16px;
        text-decoration: line-through;
        color: grey;
        display: inline-block;
        margin-left: 10px;
        vertical-align: bottom;
    }

</style>

<div class="product-price" id="productPrice">
 <!-- The price will be inserted here using JavaScript -->
</div>

<script>
function formatPrice(price) {
  const decimalRegex = /([0-9]+)(\.[0-9]{2})/;
  const decimalMatches = decimalRegex.exec(price);

  if (decimalMatches) {
    return `<span class="price-symbol">RD$</span><span class="current-price">${decimalMatches[1]}<sup>${decimalMatches[2].substring(1)}</sup></span>`;
  } else {
    return price;
  }
}

// SAMPLE
const price = "RD$15.00";
const formattedPrice = formatPrice(price);

// Insert the formatted price into the HTML element
document.getElementById('productPrice').innerHTML = formattedPrice;

</script>
```